# Why is the CakeDC users plugin creating an initial cookie response when I explicitly set different settings?

Tags: session, cakephp, cookies, cakedc

I am familiar with the cakePHP cookie and session settings but I am unsure as to why (when analyzing through the Burp Proxy Suite I am finding 2 seperate Set-Cookie responses:

```
Set-Cookie: DropZone=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: DropZone=spackr9fhhgod0lqk9glh3ch44; expires=Tue, 28-Jan-2014 23:01:37 GMT;path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

I have taken the time to set HTTPOnly and the Secure flags. What I dont understand is the first line here:

```
Set-Cookie: DropZone=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
```

Where could this Set-Cookie Header be coming from? More importantly, could this be more than an informational security threat?

I am clearly in my app/Config/core.php file setting the Session Settings:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'DropZone',
    'timeout' => 15,
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_secure' => true,
        'session.cookie_httponly' => true)
));
```

Comment: What version of the plugin (commit id?) and CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Hi Burzum, I am using CakePHP 2.4.  I am unsure what commit ID I am on as it was downloaded through the zip package on github and not through the git repo, probably downloaded just over a month or so ago.

Comment: What's the file name then? Is that you? https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues/154 Please add the info to the ticket as well. I'll check this as soon as I have time for this, maybe sunday late night.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by what is the file name?  It is the response header I receive through Burp Proxy Suite that tells me the LOGIN and LOGOUT function are where the cookie I described above is created. I spoke to James Watts and he asked me to create a ticket there for it as well.  I will attach any additional info I can including a screenshot if it allows me too.

Comment: Did you download that file? 2.0.zip The cookie is set by the RememberMe component and can be configured through it as well, see its doc block.

Comment: The only files I downloaded were the User Plugins files.  The additions to the Sessions I made in the /Config/core.php file.  Following the code I thought maybe the remember.me could be the case.  Although I currently do have the RememberMe disabled and not active.  I will have a look this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue and  I see *two* cookies, `DropZone` which is in fact the default cookie name *you've* configured plus the other cookie `Users[rememberMe]` which is used by the plugin.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration

Mine is correctly set. Also let me explain what your Cookie string means:

`Set-Cookie: DropZone=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/`

This says that your cookie named DropZone has been deleted. The next line creates it with the given settings:

`Set-Cookie: DropZone=spackr9fhhgod0lqk9glh3ch44; expires=Tue, 28-Jan-2014 23:01:37 GMT;path=/; secure; HttpOnly`

The behaviour here is correct I think, it deletes the cookie and renews it.

This cookie is definitely *not* coming from the users plugin as long as you haven't changed the name in the components setting to DropZone as well. So you should see two cookies.

---

Here is the related Github Issue: https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues/154